# How to install third party app from with in ionic app?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I am developing IOS and Android App in an Ionic. I want to install third party app on my ionic app.

Suppose my ionic app name is "X".While I am going to install it from App Store, after installation when I will open my "X" APP, One prompt should be appeared to ask the user to install the Third party App name is "Y". is it possible? 
        Also How I can check this Third party app is installed or not on the user device or phone while every time opening my "X" app?

otherwise

While Installing "X" app from app store, can we start the installation process of third-party app i.e. "Y" at the same time?

So Does these both the things or any of the above thing is possible on IOS?
I have the same question about android also.Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: any answer to this post...